# 'System.Data.Objects.ObjectSet<Webshop.Product>' does not contain a definition for 'Find' and no extension method 'Find'

Tags: c#, asp.net

Hello i am doing a webshop asp.net appliceation and have a strange error concerninig the Find command, visual studio cant find the command what do i need to do ?, I am using Visual studio 2010 because the code im trying to implement was done in visual studio 2010

### Here is the Code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace Webshop.Models
{
    public class ProductTypeModel
    {
        public string InsertProductType(ProductType productType)
        {
            try
            {

                webshopEntities db = new webshopEntities();
                db.ProductTypes.AddObject(productType);
                db.SaveChanges();

                return productType.Name + "was succesfully inserted";
            }

            catch (Exception e)
            {
                return "Error:" + e;
            }

        }

        public string UpdateProductType(int id, ProductType productType)
        {


            try
            {
                webshopEntities db = new webshopEntities();

                // Merret objekti nga db
                ProductType p = db.ProductTypes.Find(id);

                p.Name = productType.Name;


                db.SaveChanges();
                return productType.Name + "was succesfully updated";
            }

            catch (Exception e)
            {

                return "Error:" + e;


            }





        }

        public string DeleteProductType(int id)
        {
            try
            {

                webshopEntities db = new webshopEntities();
                ProductType productType = db.ProductTypes.Find(id);

                db.ProductTypes.Attach(productType);
                db.ProductTypes.DeleteObject(productType);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return productType.Name + "was succesfully deleted";
            }

            catch (Exception e)
            {
                return "Error:" + e;

            }





        }




    }








}
```

### Here is the Compiler Error

[Compiler Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZEAYB.png)

Answer (score 0):

From the error I can see you use `ObjectSet<TEntity>`, which doesn't have a `Find()` method as you can see in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.objects.objectset-1?view=netframework-4.8). If you want to use the `Find()` method, you first need to cast your ObjectSet to a List for exapmle, like this: `db.ProductTypes.ToList()` for this to work you have to have `using System.Linq`.

Comment: How can i do that can you write the code changes i need to make